# Tips for planting peonies

Tags: transplanting, peonies

I bought a couple of potted Itoh peonies to put in the ground ([Canadian zone 6a](http://www.planthardiness.gc.ca/?lang=en&m=24&speciesid=1000000&phz=phz1981-2010&bc=1), near Toronto). They're going up against a shed that faces south. They have about four square feet each.

Given my [recent failure to keep mini roses alive](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/38820/are-my-mini-roses-well-and-truly-dead) in this spot, I wanted to solicit some advice for best practices to make sure these two beauties don't face the same fate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These peonies like enriched soil, so it's a good idea to dig in some composted animal manure or good garden compost prior to planting. The problem you have to consider is the fact it's a south facing position; whilst they will survive in full sun, their blooms fade much faster than they do planted in part sun/part shade positions. If you decide to plant them there anyway, they will need watering on a regular basis until they have settled in properly, probably up to Fall. Further information here https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/flowers/peony/growing-hybrid-itoh-peonies.htm

Comment: Merci. How often do you think I should water right after transplanting? (Not on the site linked.) Is every other day enough?

Comment: If the soil feels and looks moist, do not water.  Planting near the foundation and concrete raises the pH so monitor the pH.  Yes you should water after transplanting, absolutely.  They  will need fertilizer added once your peonies get going and producing leaves.  Compost is not fertilizer.  Keep away from the base of the peony trunk.  Water when there is no moisture when you poke your finger into the soil.  Or when your plant shows any wilt.  Do not water on some schedule.  Every other day might be okay but the water needs change from newly planted to mature.

Comment: @stormy Thanks! Incidentally, with some of my potted plants on these hot days, the soil looks and feels dry every morning. Does that mean I should water them that often?? I don't want to rot the roots...

Comment: Potted plants have should all have drainage holes in the bottom of the pots - water copiously when they need it, allow the water to drain away freely beneath, and yes, on hot days, that's every day if not twice a day...

Comment: @LukeSawczak The best way to know if a plant needs water, for sure, is to lift the pot when it is dry and after you water deeply.  You will know right away whether your plant needs water.  The difference is night and day.  Lift the bottoms of your pots off the surface; of the saucer, patio, bureau using either pot feet that you can buy and they are cute...or just pieces of 1/4" tile.  This breaks the surface tension and really enhances drainage.

Comment: When you water this year, poke your hose down into the soil around your peonies to soak that soil.  Use a shovel to slice into the soil 4 to 6 inches deep...make note of how much water, how long you watered and how deep the moisture went.  How deep are the rootballs?  The soil surface might look dry but you need to actually check to see how deep that water is getting in your soil.  I always water new plants by ramming the hose down into the soil.  I find little animal tunnels that siphon the water away from the plant and learn where the water is draining TO.